# While in beta, why does my reputation need to be so high to suggest tag synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderation, tag-synonyms, reputation

I have been working on cleaning up the tags on the main freelancing site by suggesting tag wiki entries. I then came across two tags that were obviously synonyms - but I do not have a high enough reputation to suggest it (need 1250).

It seems that in its current state, anyone can create a new tag, but very few of us (if any) have the ability to suggest synonyms and clean up tags.

I suggest we allow current (invite-only) members more moderation privileges, for things like this (keeping the site clean and un-cluttered).

1. Is there a reason why we don't allow this (is vandalism an issue for invitees)?
2. How can we go about making this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag synonyms used to be something that only developers on Stack Exchange could put in place. When it was given to the community, the high rep-barrier was to discourage vandalism or incorrect tag synonyms.

It is higher still on established sites; the lowered reputation barriers are already present on beta sites (in private beta, you need 2999 less rep to cast close votes, for example)

We don't have any [moderators pro tem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore) yet, by the way. These would be the people given moderator privileges "for the time being" later into the beta when we go public.